AsyncIO: Program still runs in a synchronous manner despite using AsyncIO in Django
I have created an API named APIDummyWait5.
Now I want to test the following
- I want the API to return the result in few milliseconds.
- While the function that is being called inside the API should run in an asynchronous manner.
The API - APIDummyWait5  randomly generates a number in between 1 - 25 and then sends that as an argument to a function named get_country_details along with another parameter named country that I will be fetching from API url params.
Here is the API
class APIDummyWait5(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        print("Coming Here")
        worker = os.getpid()
        thread = threading.get_ident()

        country = request.GET.get('country')

        print(f"API wait 5 - for worker - {worker} at Thread {thread} starting at: {datetime.datetime.now()}")

        wait_time = rd.randint(1, 25)
        response = {'wait_time': wait_time, 'country': country}

        asyncio.run(main(wait_time=wait_time, country=country))

        print(f"API Wait 5 - for worker - {worker} at Thread {thread} ending at: {datetime.datetime.now()}")

        return Response({
            "data": response
        })

async def main(wait_time, country):
    result = await get_country_details(wait_time, country)

I am creating a helper function named main to call the get_country_details function.
The function - get_country_details  actually sleeps for the wait time and then calls a third party API to fetch the name and capital of a country and store it in a csv.
async def get_country_details(wait_time, country):
    worker = os.getpid()

    print(f"API Quick @ {wait_time} - for worker - {worker} starting at: {datetime.datetime.now()}")

    await asyncio.sleep(wait_time)  # Simulate waiting time

    url = f"https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/{country}"
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                
                file = pd.read_csv('country_data.csv')
                name_list = list(file['name'])
                capital_list = list(file['capital'])

                country_data = data[0]
                country = country_data['name']['common']
                capital = country_data['capital'][0]

                name_list.append(country)
                capital_list.append(capital)

                new_data = pd.DataFrame({'name': name_list, 'capital': capital_list})
                new_data.to_csv('country_data.csv', index=False)

                print(f"Asynchronously Ran Function for {wait_time} seconds.")
                return 1
            else:
                print(f"Error: Unable to fetch details for {country}")
                return None

Now if in case the wait_time = 11
then it takes 11 seconds to return the response where as it should be returned in XX milliseconds since the main API is not time consuming.
Why is this still running in a synchronous manner and what should I do to fix this?
I do not want to use threads, I am testing something with asyncio.

Your "helper function" named main (poor choice of a name) does nothing but call another function with the same arguments it was passed. How does that "help" anything? Aside from that your question is not clear. Are you saying that you want the call to asyncio.run(main(wait_time=wait_time, country=country)) to return immediately regardless of what the wait time value is? Also, APIDummyWait5.get is not returning back to its caller the results of get_country_details (whose name suggests it returns back something other than 1 or None). It's not clear to me what get is supposed to do.

The statement asyncio.run(main(wait_time=wait_time, country=country)) invokes main and blocks until main returns a result. If you want to not block then you will need some mechanism to get the result of get_country_details back to get somehow. Right now get is ignoring the results and returning the arguments it was called with. Why even bother to get the country details then?

Try to replace asyncio.run(main(wait_time=wait_time, country=country)) with asyncio.create_task(main(wait_time=wait_time, country=country)):
class APIDummyWait5(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    print("Coming Here")
    worker = os.getpid()
    thread = threading.get_ident()

    country = request.GET.get('country')

    print(f"API wait 5 - for worker - {worker} at Thread {thread} starting at: {datetime.datetime.now()}")

    wait_time = rd.randint(1, 25)
    response = {'wait_time': wait_time, 'country': country}

    asyncio.create_task(main(wait_time=wait_time, country=country))

    print(f"API Wait 5 - for worker - {worker} at Thread {thread} ending at: {datetime.datetime.now()}")

    return Response({
        "data": response
    })


Doesn't work though...@Andrey

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
